# Includes fail to resolve correctly in Xcode workspace

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having trouble linking to a static library in Xcode 5. I did read the chapter on building and using a static library in the Pro iOS 5 Tools.  What it told me to do after creating your static library, was to link against the framework in the Build Phases tab.  That part is pretty straight forward.  Then it says in the Build Settings, under "Header Search Paths", to add:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)
```

Then in order to use my static library, I just import it like so:

```
#import "ConversionCalculator/ConversionCalculator.h"
```

So this used to work up until yesterday.  I tried adding a new static library to my project which didn't seem to work.  So I cleaned my project, and tried rebuilding again, but now Xcode complains about `#import "ConversionCalculator/ConversionCalculator.h"`.  It says

Lexical or Preprocessor issue.  'ConversionCalculator/ConversionCalculator.h' file could not be found.

I was wondering if anyone has any tips on debugging this.  I've looked through different tutorials like this:
http://blog.stevex.net/2012/04/static-libraries-in-xcode/
http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/06/library-management-with-xcode-workspaces.html
http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-status-library-in-ios-tutorial

But I can't seem to find the "golden way" to link to a static lib, or how to troubleshoot why Xcode cannot find my file.  My file structure is setup on my machine like so:

```
Projects\
   DistanceCalculator\DistanceCalculator.xcodeproj
   ConversionCalculator\ConversionCalculator.xcodeproj
   DistanceCalculator.workspace
```

Like I said, this all used to work too when I followed the tutorial in Pro iOS 5 Tools book.  Now I don't know why my workspace cannot find ConversionCalculator when it has used it before.  The part I find hard is different articles say different things about the header search path, and I'm not sure what the best way to populate that field is.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I'll add that I can build for the device without errors.  But when I switch to the iPhone simulator, it gives me that error about not being able to find the file.  I also see that I get this warning:

```
ConversionCalculator was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libConversionCalculator.a' because its architectures 'i386' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386 x86_64'
```

Looking at that, I'm not sure what that means.  If it means that my library is not being built for all architectures, I just tried creating a Target that builds for all architectures according to the wenderlich article in the above link.  That seems to work as when I go to the dervieddata folder, I see for debug, release, and universal, I see the libConversionCalculator.a file.  But then when I go back into the workspace and try to rebuild the project for the simulator, I get that could not find file error and the implicit warning.

Edit #2:
I just saw a warning flag on Xcode that says upgrade to recommended Build Settings.  Now I get no errors.  Not sure what happened... but I guess no errors is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the description available in Xcode's Help topic "**Linking Against Your Library**" in chapter [Configuration Your Application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH3-SW1) in [Introduction to Using Static Libraries in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Introduction.html)
 (you may search within Xcode Help, too).

Except that I would recommend to include your headers from libraries always using angle brackets:

`#import <ConversionCalculator/ConversionCalculator.h>`

Using double quotes may inadvertently search and find files with the same name in some sub-folder relative to the file where this import directive is written. Only after there was no file in any sub-folder the preprocessor starts searching with the specified header search paths.

Using angle brackets, the preprocessor immediately searches only at the specified header search paths.

So, since you actually want to find headers for the *corresponding* library, always use angle brackets.

**Note:** If you follow the recommendation to *create* a static library project, you don't need to explicitly set a header search path in the target that links agains the library: Xcode will already add a search path:

`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/includes`

Your library headers are located in

`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/includes/<product-name>`

which are placed there through the "Copy-Files" phase of the iOS static library target, whose "Destination" is set to "Products Directory" and whose "Subpath" is set to "includes/${PRODUCT_NAME}" per default.

You may change these default settings to other reasonable and sensible values. (if you do, consider the the consequences for Xcode's default search paths!)

Comment: i got here from having exactly the problem the question describes, unfortunately the content does not match (a framework is not a static library, it is much more). this problem is also not about debugging static libraries themselves, just header include paths.


in short this is just a confusing result to find, and of no help. i'm not sure what to do though. a downvote seems wrong, but this is just a distraction if someone really has problems debugging code in a static library from inside xcode (which is a different problem, much more closely related to the title text than the question).

Comment: @jheriko Often enough, the title of a question is misleading and may not match with the actual questions stated in the post. So, I kindly suggest to ask your own question and encourage you to use a precise title ;)  There's also the possibility to edit the OPs title - if you think this is appropriate and helps others, too.

Comment: thank you. i have done this. now hopefully this useful answer will be more easily found by people with his problem. :)